# Authoring : Unusable Blu-Ray Menu on XBOX ONE (MultiAVCHD)

Tags: xbox-one, blu-ray

I am new here, and I have a problem. I burned my first Blu-Ray with menu using the MultiAVCHD software. After a successful virtual disk test, I write it all on a Blu-Ray RW test. All goes well, the PC recognizes the Blu-Ray and I can read it without problem with PowerDVD. Where I have a problem is when I try to read it on my XBOX ONE S. It recognizes the Blu-Ray and launches the menu. This one is displayed correctly, the background music too... But impossible to navigate! No button on my remote seems to work, and this in contextual as well as in general. Frustrating!

I was looking for what to do with the BDEdit software, but this one is too complex and I quickly felt lost.

If I chose the software MultiAVCHD it's because I need to burn a Blu-Ray with menu, but without re-encoding and no time / bitrate limit.

Thank you to the entire community and happy new year  !

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience using MultiAVCHD, but I've made a lot of Blu-ray discs using other methods for the past many years.

Reading your post I get a couple of thoughts:

Different Blu-ray players act differently. It's not uncommon that the disc will work fine with PowerDVD, but won't run on other players. PowerDVD is very forgiving, so it could easily be a fault on the disc.

However, since you say that the menu is displayed and everything seems to be running except the controls, it sounds like the disc is ok.

Note that the gaming consoles only lets you use the gamepad in the first port for Blu-ray controls. Any other port won't work. Maybe that's the issue?

You can find an overview of which buttons on the Xbox One gamepad maps to which functionality here: http://www.blu-play.com/developer/input-controls